# How can i call the css, in my view, using php as template engine?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a view like this:

***index.html.php:***

```
/**......
...... Some code......
**/

<link ... href="???????">

/**.....
..... Some code .....
.....**/
```

Which route should use ???

My css is in: Myproyect/web/bundles/myfolder/css/purple.css but it didnt worked.

PD:
***index.html.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Lionel Richemond - Multimedia Designer</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="web/bundles/LionelBundle/css/purple.css" />
```

Comment: Please share your actual code, rather than just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be new to this based on the question, so I'm going to work from the ground up and you can clarify things from there.

Here are the basics.  Let's simplify your hierarchy and say your project is organized like so:

- MyProject

  - bundles

    - mycss.css
  - index.php

Let's assume your website root path points to MyProject so that your URL looks like this:

```
http://mysite.ext/index.php
```

If you want to include CSS in your index.php page, it would look like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='bundles/mycss.css' />
```

When the browser looks at this it's going to look relative to the file it THINKS it's executing.  If it thinks it's loading /index.php, then you are golden.  However, if you have MVC style routing, relative paths won't work.  Let's say that your route looks something like this:

```
http://mysite.ext/controller/action
```

If that is the case, the browser is going to look for:

```
http://mysite.ext/controller/bundles/mycss.css
```

To fix this, you need to use a URL starting from your root web directory like so:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='/bundles/mycss.css' />
```

By adding that slash to the front of the path, the browser knows to start from the base URL rather than trying to work up from the directory it thinks it's in.

Answer (score 1):

Just have your file named "index.php". You do not need the .html.php. You can now write full blown html in your .php file, this will work by itself. Include your link tag in the head section of your html code as usual, no change there. Now, wherever you need to do some php work, simply add your

```
<?php ?>
```

tags as usual and code away. The php will execute inside the page based on where it is in the html. If it is above your html tag, for example, it will all execute before any of the html is rendered. If your php chunk generates a table, you will need to place this chunk where you would have written the table if it were in html (not above your html tag).

I believe your issue is that your path is incorrect. You are using a relative path. So if your index.php file is at C:/web/site1/index.php and your css file is at C:/web/site1/purple.css then your link href should just be purple.css. If index.php exists in the same directory as a css/ folder where purple.css lives, then your link href should just be css/purple.css. Check into relative paths

Comment: when i do this, it says that the template name is not valid like this, and the correct format should be bundle:section:template.format.engine

Comment: In the controller I render the view like this: return $this->render('LionelMainBundle:IndexView:index.html.php');    is there any mistake ?

Comment: what is the path to your index.html.php file